# FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations() doesn't work when battery saver is on

Tags: android, animation, fragment, battery-saver

I'm using custom animation (sliding from left to right) on transition between fragments. But when battery saver is on after calling FragmentTransaction.commit() second fragment is not showing.

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_help_container, newFragment);
    // Start the animated transition.
    ft.commit();
```

This is what I found in LogCat related to this issue.

```
    02-18 20:33:26.908 932-932/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=
            android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews$TextViewDrawableAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1502)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1373)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.reapply(RemoteViews.java:2795)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:2064)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotification(BaseStatusBar.java:1939)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:487)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1.0"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue without the crash but my fragments don't appear. I found that if the animation is using a set animator that it consistently does not work but if it is a simple objectAnimator without the set then it works fine. Can you post your slide_in_left and slide_out_right files?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using set element, added content of files. So what do I need to change? Remove set element and make objectAnimator as a root element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the set seemed to work in most cases for me. When the device is in battery mode the objectAnimator seems to behave as a noOp so you wont have the nice animations but you don't have to worry about any complications. If you need to have more complex animations that need the set (say a fade and translate at the same time) then you will probably have to add a helper method to set the custom animation. In my case I actually had the view that was supposed to animate in just not show up because of the set

```
    /**
 * NOTE: on lollipop+ the battery save screws with the animations. in most cases its fine but in some it actually prevents
 * the fragment from displaying. because of that I am creating this helper that must always be used
 */
public static void setCustomAnimation(Activity activity, FragmentTransaction transaction, int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)
{
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
            && powerManager.isPowerSaveMode())
    {
        return;
    }
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, enter, exit);
}
```

Comment: I removed set, but fragments still disappear so I ended up with same solution that you've proposed.

Comment: @John any thoughts on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483783/valueanimator-doesnt-work-as-expected-when-battery-saver-is-enabled-api-21) ?